# The Winter Bash 2018 Leaderboard is redirecting to an error page

Tags: bug, winter-bash-2018, winterbash-leaderboard

Clicking on the leaderboard link redirects to `https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/leaderboard` (instead of just `/leaderboard`). That page says,
[image: oops something bad happened]

I just wanted to see if Alexander O'Mara was winning again, but my hopes have been dashed. What happened to the leaderboard?

Comment: Don't worry, I'm not winning yet. Still gotta get that Member of The Hand hat.

Comment: ... and now I'm in the lead with 3 other people again.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever was wrong, it's working now, and Alexander O'Mara is currently number 4 on the SE leaderboard:

[image]

Comment: Well, on SO, Alexander O'Mara is #11th rank, earning sixteen hats, see the leaderboard